# EXCEL - Index a value based on a text string and a number within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having some trouble with a sheet I am working on.

I have two sheets, a property list, and a lookup table. I am trying to pull a value from the lookup table, but this is where I am hitting a snag.

I need to find this value based on a text string (property type) and a number (total floor area). The issue I am having is that the floor area does not exactly match the values in the lookup table, so I have added two additional columns indicating the lower and upper ends of a range. But since there are multiple property types, there is essentially 6 small tables. I have divided the table into various named ranges/ indirects, which has helped somewhat, but I still cant get the results I am after.

The Lookup looks something like this (below will be link to an extract with the full table on dropbox (can you directly attach files?))

```
Dwelling Type / Dwelling Code / No. Bedrooms / Median Floor Area / Start Point / End Point
MidTerrace House / MIDENDHOUSE /    1        /    53.7           /  0          / 60.65
MidTerrace House / MIDENDHOUSE /    2        /    67.6           /  60.65      / 76
Detatched House / DETHOUSE     /    2-        /   99.7           /  0         / 102.3
Detatched House / DETHOUSE     /    3        /   104.9           /  102.3     / 125.35
```

The relevant part of the property list looks like this - each row representing an individual address ~5000 in total.

```
Total Floor Area / Dwelling type match / Dwelling Code /No. Bedrooms
74.54            / Semi-detached house /   SEMIHOUSE   /
47.5             / Mid-terrace house   / MIDENDHOUSE   /
```

What I need is the number of bedrooms for each property on this sheet to be populated, based on the dwelling code and the range in which the total floor area falls on the lookup table sheet.

I have tried using LOOKUP, VLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH, INDIRECT,array formulas, and all manner of combinations. I feel like the answer is just staring me in the face, but I just can see it. I either get errors, or incorrect matches (in the case of LOOKUP).

The following is the link to dropbox with the extract of the sheet,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlv5z0ylm5lg3ym/Lookup%20Sheet%20Example.xlsx?dl=0

The sheets are malleable so adding columns is not a problem and I understand some VBA, so all solutions are appreciated.

If you need any further info, please let me know.

Thanks

Callum

Comment: I couldn't get what you are trying to do.... Your data is located in `Property List` and you wanna - in another seet - create a summary of your `Property List`?

Comment: or you wanna fill your property sheet number of rooms column based on the median total floor area summarized in lookup table?

Comment: Your second comment is correct, each line of the property list sheet is an individual property (roughly 5000 rows) which contains the floor area of that property. I need to add to this the number of bedrooms based on the dwelling type and median floor area on the lookup table sheet.

I will edit the original question to be clearer about this.

Comment: I think you may be able to take advantage of `VLOOKUP`'s "closest match" behavior when its last parameter is `TRUE` or absent.  If you fix your floor areas to a standardized decimal length (both before and after the decimal point with padding 0s), you can concatenate the dwelling code and the square footage into a lookup key that, when sorted alphabetically, will sort by dwelling code and then by square footage.  You can then vlookup based on this column.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around this question... what would the example solutions (bedroom count) be for the 2 you listed?
`Total Floor Area / Dwelling type match / Dwelling Code /No. Bedrooms
74.54            / Semi-detached house /   SEMIHOUSE   /
47.5             / Mid-terrace house   / MIDENDHOUSE   /`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the solution you're looking for.

First of all, I simply converted your tables into Structured Tables (Basically select the tables you built, and then press CONTROL-T *(or under the INSERT Ribbon, click Tables and convert them into structured tables)*).

I gave your tables the same name as the sheets (PropertyList and LookupTable).  I then added this formula to the "No. Bedrooms" column:

```
=COUNTIFS(LookupTable[Dwelling Code],[Dwelling Code],LookupTable[Start Point],"<="&[Total Floor Area])+NUMBERVALUE(VLOOKUP([Dwelling Code],LookupTable[Dwelling Code]:LookupTable[No. of bedrooms],2,FALSE),"-")-1
```

**How it works:**

1. We want to get a count of all the cells that match both the [Dwelling Code] and where [Start point] (floor size) is less than or equal to [Total Floor Area].
2. But since some of these Dwelling Codes start at Bedroom count of "2 -", we need to account for those, so we do a Vlookup of the first [Dwelling Code] cell and see what their starting [No. of bedroom] value is, and add that to our total.
3. We use the Formula "NUMBERVALUE" to extract the 2 from the text so that it doesn't cause #VALUE errors.
4. Finally, we make a correction at the end with a minus one (-1) because we're double counting the first cell of each dwelling code when we're using both VLOOKUP and COUNTIFS.  (we're adding 1 or 2 each time with our vlookup, so we need to subtract 1).

If, for some reason, you don't want to use Structured Tables, then this very convoluted formula will do the same thing, but you need to put it in Cell G2 on Sheet "Property List".

```
=COUNTIFS('Lookup Table'!$C$3:$C$24,'Property List'!F2,'Lookup Table'!$F$3:$F$24,"<="&'Property List'!A2)+NUMBERVALUE(VLOOKUP('Property List'!F2,'Lookup Table'!$C$3:$C$24:'Lookup Table'!$D$3:$D$24,2,FALSE),"-")-1
```

Comment: Sorry for he delayed response (been called away for the weekend). I'll give  this a try at some point today, and report back whether it has worked.

Comment: No problem, I hope the solution works, if not, let me know.  Also, mark as an answer if it does work, thanks!